# Passing controller argument to template, symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, controllers

I have a route like this:
index:

```
path:     /{category}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Index:index, category: "default" }
requirements:
categoria: "foo|bar|this|or|that"
```

and the relative controller is:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($category)
    {
        $data = array("Content1", "Content2");
        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('data' => $familiari));
    }
}
?>
```

What if I want to use the value stored in $category inside the template index.html.twig? I tried passing the variable category with the render function but I get an error! Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of render() is an array of parameters that can be accessed in the rendered template. So if you pass $category in like this:

```
  public function indexAction($category)
    {
        $data = array("Content1", "Content2");
        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index.html.twig', 
              array('data' => $familiari, 'category'=>$category));
    }
```

Then you can access it in the template using:

```
{{ category }}
```